# Filling a google form from R

Tags: r, rcurl, google-forms

I would like to use R to fill the following (demo) form:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1daaGo7XZaaGGPvTOconG8QZItqaLeIZmSpPPcgxTJvg/viewform

Any suggestions on how this might be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Main issue is google forms use weird id fields for form entries. You should be able to use rcurl to post once you get ids figured out.

Comment: Hi Thomas, given that we know the url, can you suggest code that performs the submission of some answers?

Comment: Spacedman's answer is pretty much exactly what I would suggest. There's no way to know the name values without manually looking at the source for each form.

Comment: Check this I found this workable :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714110/can-you-submit-a-restful-request-to-a-google-forms-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outline:

Step 1: scrape the FORM element from the web page using standard R web scraping techniques and find the `name` attribute of all the form widgets you want to fill in. For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="entry.1945263135" value="Option 1" id="group_1945263135_1" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="Option 1">
```

gives you the name of the option 1 radio button from Question 1.

Step 2: get the `POST` address by scraping the attributes of the `FORM` element.

Step 3: Use `RCurl:postForm` to send the form, constructing the `.params` parameter to map values to widget names. See [RCurl docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RCurl/docs/.postForm) for that. Exact values for each parameter depends on the widget (checkbox, radio, text, etc) so I won't go into specifics here.

The tricky tricky bit is whether you are trying to make this general for any google form, or if this is a one-shot and you are happy to encode the `name` attributes into your code. In fact if you only want this to work for one form you can just view the page source and hard-code all the names and `POST` address into your code with no scraping required. Then its just a matter of constructing the `.params` for `postForm`, and if that's the problem then I suggest you read docs, try things, and then ask more specific questions when you fail.

Comment: Thanks Barry, I'll dig into it later on :)