# Can you submit a Restful request to a google forms api?

Tags: google-forms, google-forms-api

I want to use google forms to collect questionnaire responses but with a much more custom UI for doing so. Is there a way to send in responses from my custom application to my google forms api?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the endpoint to fill the google form directly.
Steps -:

1. Create a google sheet.
2. Click on the Tool menu to create a google form.
3. Then create some google forms fields.
4. Now in the right top corner click on the 3 dots and select the Pre-fields link form.
5. Fill the info and click on the Get link and copy the link
6. Now you have a URL with the endpoints like this
   Endpoints are

entry.1651815625.

entry.952362665

Google Sheet Link for Form -: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfxoz5dqXC-_LoGJWZCPasww6woHcOl0s48PYcCj-72uUJoBQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1651815625=Radha&entry.952362665=Krishna"

To Convert this link to this way

"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfssz5dqXC-_LoGJWZCP93ww6woHcOl0s48PYcCj-72uUJoBQ/formResponse?&submit=Submit?usp=pp_url&entry.1651815625=Radha&entry.952362665=Krishna"

Instead of "viewform" you have to write "formResponse?&submit=Submit"

Now you can pass your own value and hit this URL to submit your google form directly.

For more info, you can watch this video from The Coding Bus
https://youtu.be/PVM7h5QCnnM

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the form's layout, it is possible to update it from your application using the Google Forms API. However, the Google Forms API currently does not support sending responses to your form, as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest)

Comment: why is that? that feels incredible undermining considering there could be scenarios where pipielines and move data from other sources to google forms.

Comment: My guess would come from the business-side, Google Form is meant for non-programmer user who wants to create simple form and save the response to the excel. However for our kind (programmer) we can send the API data directly to the excel

Answer (score 1):

At this time the Google Forms REST API doesn't support creating form responses as the Form.responses resource only includes two methods: get and list. Ref. https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms.responses?hl=en

You might use the Forms Service from Google Apps Script to create Google Forms  Responses programmatically. To call this service from your app you might create a web-app in order have a HTTP GET / POST request end-point or use the Google Apps Script REST API.

Another option might be to use a "hack" to emulate the Google Forms POST request. See [Auto-Fill or automate a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61849716/1595451)

Related

- [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20108511/1595451)
- [how to create a google form response with app script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36831901/1595451)
- [Load form responses with script in sheet - Create initial forms with nothing but an ID number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38257224/1595451)

Comment: That seems like something google forms didn't intend for 3rd party apps to use and the concern would be that they can suspend that API at any point of time.

Comment: Have you considered the first option (Google Apps Script)?

Comment: Oh just realized that those are different concepts, so you are suggesting interacting with the Google AS Rest API and have that run the Google Forms submission

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a way to send in responses from my custom application to my google forms api?"

Assuming that you mean user supplied questionnaire responses, then the short answer to your question is No!

Currently, Google Forms does not accept questionnaire responses via the google forms api. The [google forms api](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest) is intended only for managing your google forms documents and not for accepting user responses.

However, considering that the user responses submitted from a google form are ultimately saved into a google sheet, you may be able to send in user questionnaire responses from your custom application using the [google sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

Keep in mind though that it can get tricky trying to make updates programmatically to data in google sheets. If your use case will not include making updates then you should be fine otherwise you're probably better off just using your favourite db storage system.

Answer (score -1):

I have codified the details mentioned by above answers.

Here is what I did in R

```r
gf_url_parse<- function(gfurl){
  l_entries <- list()
  et <- strsplit(gfurl, "&entry.")[[1]]
  if(length(et)>1){
    entries <- et[-1]
    vals <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(entries, "="), `[[`,2))
    entries <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(entries, "="), `[[`,1))
    entries_d <- data.frame(entries, vals, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    l_entries <-lapply(split(entries_d, entries_d$entries), function(x) x$vals)
    l_entries <- l_entries[unique(entries_d$entries)]
  }
  l_entries
}

gf_url_make <- function(entries, gfurl_sample){
  base_url <- strsplit(gfurl_sample, "&entry.")[[1]][1]
  var_part <- paste0(
    "&entry.",
    unlist(
      lapply(
        names(entries), 
        function(nn){
          paste0(nn,"=",entries[[nn]])
        }
      )
    ), 
    collapse = "")
  paste0(base_url, var_part)
}

gf_url_submit <- function(gfurl_compiled){
  gfurl_compiled_prep <- gsub(
    pattern = "/viewform?",replacement = "/formResponse?&submit=Submit?", 
    x = gfurl_compiled)
  tryCatch(
    suppressWarnings(RCurl::postForm(gfurl_compiled_prep)), 
    error = function(e) NULL
  )
  invisible(0)
}
```

Comment: it's a basic and crude implementation... try with Google Forms prefilled link